# Is it possible to use Globus Java WS Core container for developing the Spring Framework based grid service?

Tags: grid, globus-toolkit

Is it possible to use Globus Java WS Core container for developing the Spring Framework based grid service ? If yes then how to configure Spring listeners ?

Comment: I think Globus is using a derivative of Axis _1_, so getting Spring to work with it is going to be “interesting”. (What a fun euphemism!) If you only need it for support for proxy certificates (reading/securing connections) then there are other solutions which are much easier to integrate.